# Type definition for property names of function returning void

Tags: typescript, rpc, conditional-types

I'm currently writing a small RPC library for a project I'm working on. To ensure some level of correctness I'm using typescript to do some typechecking. I got the initial implementation working and while doing some refactoring I ran into a problem with some of the conditional types.

The idea is to have an RPC service definition along the lines of the interface below and be able to separate calls that return a value (call) to those that don't (notify).

```js
export default interface ExampleService {
  add(a: number, b: number): number;
  sub(a: number, b: number): number;
  log(message: string): void;
}
```

Up to now I was returning Promises and it was working fine, but switching the return type to literal/void the types are no longer correct

```js
type CallMethods<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => void ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

type NotifyMethods<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => void ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

I'm expecting `CallMethods<ExampleServer>` to be `"add" | "sub"` and `NotifyMethods<ExampleService>` to be `"log"`

But with this type definition I'm getting `CallMethods<ExampleService>` as `never` and `NotifyMethods<ExampleService>` as `"add" | "sub" | "notify"`...

My assumption is that it has to do with substituability as explained in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you noted, it is indeed because non-void returning functions are assignable to void returning functions. To get around this, simply check the return type *only*. Do not compare function types as a whole here.

```
type CallMethods<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> extends void ? never : K : never;
}[keyof T];

type NotifyMethods<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => any ? ReturnType<T[K]> extends void ? K : never : never;
}[keyof T];
```

Comparing types to void with `extends` does not have this behavior.

```
type Y = number extends void ? true : false;
//   ^? false
```

This also works if the return type of a function is nullable (includes null or undefined).

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28CWA7GYKNAY2DgFERUBbMTYAZSIDccy4BvAWACg44qBAgAUqAFxw86GgCMiAGjizJ0uUQCUqmfKgBuPgIDO6WWO3qoSlVJ2aLug-ziYIAcxE1gRo6jfBJIxgofDctOBYIHAQnQ0QIRhh0ZGQRcKCQvDc4AB84dDwkZHxgGLgAenK4IwALCCwEZXJ8OABhVExMAFlgGDqEIz44sCgIMEkABj0KqpGxohgcb2q6hqkIeHk4fBJMdCQEPgBfId4YAE8wcnbOnr6IAYAeABUAPjgAXi44gG0AaW2eDgAGtgOcIMg4M8ALqSZ7-aFwUCEQpGOAiAB0WNQUDcRkkqDw5x+0I0n3ehPOcAA-HAAEq9dBQPDPS7AF4I97I4CoiJRRq0vDAFhEOCSAGqYVEJxHH6g8GQmGxM5suAAOQ2OGQ5zu-SML3eXx4zn+gJBYIhUNhUIRSJAKIG6KxGJxeIJRJJZI+FKJNPpjOZrKuHL+0K59p5jsi0T9EqkUqgYvjIv0xzlFsV0OVFyuUM+bQ63V6eseVFo9CYrHYwFeThz5AAGvmNYttbqHvqy3QGMwoGwyLXTvW4ABNfNqXR2h1o6MCuDBdDkSRoTBGYBOSoCOAAPWpQA)

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's working perfectly, I had tried something not too far from it but I didn't think (or try) to have compound extend statements with ReturnType after only filtering the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this (see [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=16&ssc=56&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAE2AMwIYFcA28CWA7GYKNAY2DgFERUBbMTYAZSIDccy4BvAKDjlQQIAFKgBccPOhoAjIgBo408ZJlEAlMqmyoAbl5wAzumkjNqqAqUSt6s9r19MEAOZCawAwdTPg4gzCh8Zw04FggcBD0AX25uGABPMHIAYVRMTABZYBgACwgEAwAeABUAPjgAXi59AG0AaTh8OABrYHiIZDhigF1xYvruuFBCPAK4IQA6KdQoZwNxVDx4mu61SvKhfGQiOAAlIZARsYA5CDxjrExUaQZCrZ2ALVK1gH44BuVgFiJomtb2zo9PRxRLkU4wHDIeJZXL5IplSrVPj1Rp4FptDpdXpdAYHI4GcZTCYzOYLJYrNYVDb3KB7PHAUYE07nS7XW40uBPV4SL47cR1X7-TFA2IJJJwVLpGF5AoAGRw-kRksy2RlRSotHoTFY7GApT0YrBEAhUOlcPliqq4Mh0NVcMKGroDGYUDYZH1QA))

```
export default interface ExampleService {
  add(a: number, b: number): number;
  sub(a: number, b: number): number;
  log(message: string): void;
}

type CallMethods<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => (infer R extends NonNullable<infer Z>) ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

type NotifyMethods<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends (...args: any[]) => (infer R extends NonNullable<infer Z>) ? never : K;
}[keyof T];

type CallMethodsList = CallMethods<ExampleService>;
type NotifyMethodsList = NotifyMethods<ExampleService>;
```

In order to detect void return type I've added NonNullable check. Downside of this solution is that return type of `null` or `undefined` would also classify as NotifyMethods but I couldn't find other way around it for now.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion. having non nullable might be actually be useful, I will keep that in mind